# Vanity name servers with .no domains

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver

I created vanity name servers e.g. ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com that are just maskеа and are pointed to rackspace free dns service. In other words ns1.example.com points to dns1.stabletransit.com and ns2.example.com points to dns2.stabletransit.com(stabletransit.com are rackspace's nameservers). In general it works fine and I can forward domains to ns1.example.com and they will work correctly and redirected to dns1.stabletransit.com. However for .no(norway) domains I stumbled into the following error:

```
 The nameserver ns1.example.com is not correctly configured. It has the following NS records in the zone file for somedomain.no:

    dns1.stabletransit.com dns2.stabletransit.com

This does not correspond with the nameservers you have entered, which are:

    ns1.example.com ns2.example.com

The list you enter must be identical to the list of NS records returned by each nameserver on the list.

For .no domains the nameservers must be configured correctly before the delegation can be completed. Not all ISPs are aware of this. Please contact the administrators of the nameservers you are trying to use, and ask them to create a valid zone file for somedomain.no on all the nameservers.
```

This is the error message that I got when I try to point .no domains to my vanity name servers. I will be thanlful if someone can expain why this happens and how can I fix it. As far as I understand this is a correct way to mask name servers by creating vanity name servers, so I'm not sure where I'm mistaken.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why would you want vanity names for this type of thing anyways?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the "real" nameserver for the domain tells that `dns1.sabletransit.com` and `dns2.stabletransit.com` are the authoritative nameservers for this domain. (NS record)

The .no registry seems to check this.

I don't think rackspace free dns allows you to change this, so I don't think there's anything you can do.

Answer (score 0):

This is possibly due to DNS changes of `example.com` not being propagated yet. Or because you did not poin't them to your vanity nameservers yet.

Comment: The propagation should be finished as I did it 2 weeks ago. One more thing that is that I created ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com as glue records of example.com. I'm not sure if this matters, but now I see that many tutorials are saying that I should simply create A record for ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com and point them to the corresponding IPs. However instead of making A records I created them as glue records. Not sure if this matters, but it is something that I noticed as a difference from the tutorials that I read.

Comment: The problem is that rackspace announces "itself" as DNS for the .NO domain. If you can manage to change the NS records to your "vanity" names, if could work.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get this. To point which NS records to the "vanity" names?

Comment: The NS records of the .NO domain

Comment: yes, if I forward the .no domain directly to the rackspace's name servers it will work and of course not show this error. But still not sure how to avoid the error if I want to point the .no domain to my masked vanity nameservers.